# What is empty print() doing in general or the ideea in loops?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have my code

```
for x in range(1,6):
   for y in range(1,6):
      print(x, end="")
    print()
```

Without `print()` I will have `11111222223333344444455555`
So the empty  `print()` in my inner loop is like a new line (`\n`)  every time I complete a loop?

Comment: yes, `print()` will just print a newline.

Comment: See [the docs on `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print): "If no *objects* are given, `print()` will just write *end*" where `end='\n'` by default.

Comment: btw, the empty `print()` is in the outer loop, not the inner loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in Python has a number of default parameters. We can take a look at what the documentation writes:

```py
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

You see that by default `end = '\n'`. This is a design-decision that is based on the judgement that in most cases people would like to end their prints by a newline. This means that performing a print without supplying any arguments will just print out the value for `end`, which by default prints a newline. This behaviour explains what you see.

Furthermore, you can also see how a default value is chosen for separating arguments to print. You could i.e. do

```py
print("str1", "str2", "str3", sep=":")
```

which would print

```py
str1:str2:str3
```

But again, a default `' '` that probably suits more cases has been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `print()` prints its arguments and then prints a newline. If there are no arguments, it just prints the newline.

You've disabled the newline with the `end=""` option in the inner `print()` calls, so there's no newline between the repetitions of the same number.

In order to get a newline between the numbers, you use an empty `print()`, which behaves as described above.